# Can all programs be broken down into if-statements?

Tags: if-statement

Probably a really stupid question, but whatever.
Theoretically speaking, everything is binary. Either a 1 or a 0.
Similar to an if-else.

Comment: No, they can't.  The one-sentence reason is: you need loops too.  For a longer explanation, [start reading here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability).

Comment: This might not be an appropriate question for stackoverflow, but I don't see it as being a "stupid" question. It's exactly the sort of thing a programming-naive or computer science-naive person might ask. I hope a well thought out actual answer is given.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote the OP for attitude, but decided not to. It's a good beginner question, not stupid at all.

Comment: It might get a decent answer on cs.stackexchange.com.